# Regex match complex substring

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a json stored in MySQL and I want to find matches using regex. I was trying to achieve this by building a query with REGEXP instead of LIKE.

```
{"type":"4","Record channels HDCVI":{"1":"4","3":"16"},
"Supported standarts HDCVI DVR":{"0":"HDCVI","2":"IP","3":"AHD","4":"Analog"},
"Record resolution HDCVI DVR":{"1":"FullHD 1080p"},
"HDD amount":{"1":"2","2":"4"},
"Specs HDCVI DVR":{"0":"2x HDMI","1":"TV-out","2":"Videoanalytics","3":"eSATA","5":"RS-485"}}
```

For example, I need to get all the records with 4 Record channels HDCVI.

So, my idea is to look for a substring like this:

```
"Record channels HDCVI":{" ... :"4" ... "}
```

and instead of three dots there should be placeholders like any amount of any characters BUT this expression should stop with the first match of closing curly bracket.

This selects substring till the last 4"} under HDD amount section. Can't figure it out.

```
/Record channels HDCVI.+"4"}/g
```

Comment: Yikes. Which MySQL version are you using? 5.7.8 has a json type which has pretty simple json search: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html and https://scotch.io/tutorials/working-with-json-in-mysql

Comment: So far, I'm on 5.7 but cant be sure that production version will match

Comment: please provide sql fiddle

Comment: Can you at least show us two examples of JSON, one which matches, and one which does not match?

Comment: Use the JSON functions, not regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this:

`/"Record channels HDCVI:{[^}]+:"4"/g`

Comment: If "4" is the first value in the list of values, the regex won't match it. However, looking at your regex, I realize that I don't need anything after "4" in my regex. :)

Comment: from the examples, it looks like the "4" he's looking for is always the second in a pair, but I may be wrong. It's an easy fix.

Comment: It might be that it is, but it's better to not bet on it. :)

Comment: Also, won't the first example with the non-greedy quantifier will give false positives? It'll match any `"4"` in the JSON block after `"Record channels HDCVI":{`

Comment: @Zak: yes, you are correct. I didn't think of that, so lazy quantifiers don't really help here. I will edit the answer - and give you an upvote too.

Comment: Thanks @brian-stephens!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT * WHERE field REGEXP '"Record channels HDCVI":{[^}]*"4"';
```

However, I can't imagine that it will be particularly fast across a lot of records.

Anyhow, the important bit is `{[^}]*"4"`, which breaks down to:

```
{     -- match the opening brace
[^}]* -- match 0 or more characters that are not a closing brace
"4"   -- match literal "4"
```

If a closing brace occurs before the `"4"` then the pattern won't match.

Comment: Thank you for the query example, helps a lot!